# DialogService pass Object as parameter in ShowDialog

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, dialog, prism

I want to open a dialog in Prism WPF. Executing a command in my ViewModel named `ExecuteOpenDialog` it gets a `CommandParameter` named `soItem`. I would like to pass this parameter to my dialog.

```
private void ExecuteOpenDialog(SOItem soItem)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(soItem.Name);
    ShowDialog(soItem);
}
```

Looks like the `DialogParameters` only be `string`s? Is that right?

```
private void ShowDialog(SOItem soItem)
{
    var message = msg;
    //using the dialog service as-is
    _dialogService.ShowDialog(typeof(DialogWindow).Name, new DialogParameters(soItem), r =>
    {
        if (r.Result == ButtonResult.None)
            Title = "Result is None";
        else if (r.Result == ButtonResult.OK)
            Title = "Result is OK";
        else if (r.Result == ButtonResult.Cancel)
            Title = "Result is Cancel";
        else
            Title = "I Don't know what you did!?";
    });
}
```

Any idea how can I pass my `SOItem` to my dialog as a parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, create a `DialogParameters` instance and add the `soItem` with a key using the `Add` method. The constructor `DialogParameters` is a **query**, where you can only add string values.

```
private void ShowDialog(SOItem soItem)
{
   var message = msg;
   //using the dialog service as-is
   var dialogParameters = new DialogParameters();
   dialogParameters.Add("MyItem", soItem);

   _dialogService.ShowDialog(typeof(DialogWindow).Name, dialogParameters, r =>
   {
      if (r.Result == ButtonResult.None)
         Title = "Result is None";
      else if (r.Result == ButtonResult.OK)
         Title = "Result is OK";
      else if (r.Result == ButtonResult.Cancel)
         Title = "Result is Cancel";
      else
         Title = "I Don't know what you did!?";
   });
}
```

Alternatively, you can use a collection intializer to add key-value pairs.

```
var dialogParameters = new DialogParameters
{
   {"MyItem", soItem}
};
```

Implement the `IDialogAware` interface in your dialog view model. There is an `OnDialogOpened` override that is triggered when the dialog is opened. There you can get the dialog parameters using an indexer `parameters["MyItem"]` (which returns an `object`) or the generic `GetValue<T>` method with casts the item to the desired type.

```
public class MyDialogViewModel : BindableBase, IDialogAware
{

   // ...other code, overrides, properties.

   private SOItem _soItem;
   public SOItem SOItem
   {
      get => _soItem;
      set => SetProperty(ref _soItem, value);
   }

   public virtual void OnDialogOpened(IDialogParameters parameters)
   {
      SOItem = parameters.GetValue<SOItem>("MyItem");
   }
}
```

Comment: Great! Thank you. That's exactly what I'm looking for. I have a `ItemsControl` inside a `ScrollViewer`. My `DataTemplate` is a custom control, and it have buttons. Those buttons opening the dialog and I'm sending the actual clicked `SOItem` for the dialog.